# What should the permissions and ownership for Drupal on LAMP stack?

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, cpanel

What has me confused is why a directory or part of my Drupal site to suddenly return the message of "Forbidden" - that I, as first use, cannot access various parts of the site in the admin area.  I changed the permission on the default/sites/files directory to 777.  That probably is giving to too much access to everyone.  However, it was only after doing that, that I got a message of Forbidden - that I don't have access to various parts of the admin area.  I am the first user.
          I changed the permissions on this directory because when I tried to update some modules, I got an error that file could not be created.
          I have cpanel/whm on a dedicated vps server.  So, one issue is how to find out what the user and group ownership should be on a server that hosts various domains through cpanel.  It appears that for other accounts have user:owner permissions that match the account name.  I am not sure if the default group:owner should remain as www-data:www-data for example, on Ubuntu or if cpanel/whm says, "make the apache group and user equal to the account name."
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to assume you're talking about Drupal 7, but really, there's little difference in this case.

Try reading about permissions [here](https://drupal.org/node/244924)

Comment: So, I was reading that page.  I had actually consulted the page.  It assumes that the server is running as user www-data.  How can I find out what user:group apache is running as in a cpanel/whm based environment.  It is a dedicated vps but I setup cpanel/whm for just a few clients.  Other clients of mine are on shared hosting.

Comment: do you have access to httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple that the folder should have user:user ownership and correct permissions with folders having 755 permissions respectively. The server might be running on suphp hence you cannot have wrong user with wrong permissions.